# Remove Special char from the string

Tags: java, regex

Hi folks i try to remove special char and digits from the string every thing works fine but the char 'h' has been print in prefix and suffix i don't know why it has printed guide me what mistake i have done...

```
  String str = "<h1>Hi buddy!!you @ $ did a Great job . <h1>";
  String str1 = str.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{M}]", " ");
  System.out.println(str1);
```

My Expecting Output

```
Hi buddy  you did a Great job
```

But i got

```
h Hi buddy  you did a Great job h
```

Comment: You are getting what you asked for.  You are removing everything except a letter and a mark.

Comment: @devnull yes i am removing everything except a letter and a mark

Comment: Use a HTML parser to get rid of the tags and then remove the marks.

Comment: As mentioned above, `h` is being printed because you _asked_ for it.  You asked to retain the letters, didn't you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should be using a HTML parser to get rid of the tags before removing everything except the letters and the marks.

Should you insist upon using regex to remove the tags, you could instead say:

```
String str1 = str.replaceall("<[^>]*>", "").replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{M}]", " ");
```

i.e. remove the tags before ...

Comment: @user3280500 `.replaceall("<[^>]*>", "")` removes the tags from the string, i.e. it gets rid of `<h1>` and so on.  The second part does what you were doing!

Answer (score 2):

The two `h`s come from the `<h1>` tags that you have in your input source:

```
<h1>Hi buddy!!you @ $ did a Great job . <h1>
 ^                                       ^
 |                                       |
 + ------------- Here and here ----------+
```

If you do not want to see them, find the tags, and remove them before calling `replaceAll`. A quick way to do it would be applying `"<\\p{Alnum}+>"` regex in a separate call of `replaceAll`. It is OK for learning experiments, but is too dirty for production. If you need to do this reliably, get an HTML parser to remove the tags.

Comment: is there is any other way to remove html tags special char and digits and . operator

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. It will work..

```
     String str = "<h1>Hi buddy!!you @ $ did a Great job . <h1>";       
     String str1 = str.replaceAll("<[^>]+>", "");
     String str2 = str1.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{M}]", " ");
     System.out.println(str2);
```

Comment: sorry frnd using ur code i got the following output Hi buddy!!you @ $ did a Great job .

Answer (score 0):

This will delete if more then one continuous space find to one space,remove the tag and remove all the special charcter.

```
 String str = "<h1>Hi buddy!!you @ $ did a Great job . <h1>";
    //  String str1 = str.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{M}]", " ");

      String str1 =  str.replaceAll("<[^>]+>", "").replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{M}]", "      
      ").replaceAll("\\s+", " ");

      System.out.println(str1);
```

output:

```
 Hi buddy you did a Great job
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this program it will work

```
public class StringFunction{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String str = "<h1>Hi buddy!!you @ $ did a Great job . <h1>";
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("<[^>]+>", "").replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{M}]", " "));

}
}
```